# how to read a 34Gb stata (.dta) file In python

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I am trying to read a 34Gb Stata (.dta) file but keep getting a "MemoryError" message it's obvious that my 16Gb ram is not enough.

I tried to test an 11Mb Stata file with:

```
dtafile = 'E:/test file.dta'
df = pd.read_stata(dtafile)
a = df.head()
print(a)
```

I got the correct output as:

```
   app_id    inventor_id  ...  lagged_generality_FYnormalized       _merge
0  101985                 ...                        1.038381  matched (3)
1  102019  SCHOTTEK 2827  ...                        0.830110  matched (3)
2  102019  KUELLMER 2827  ...                        0.830110  matched (3)
3  102019   DICKNER 2827  ...                        0.830110  matched (3)
4  102562    VINEGAR 986  ...                        0.825088  matched (3)

[5 rows x 1448 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I tried the same with the 34Gb file I got a "MemoryError" message.
The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\work.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pd.read_stata(dtafile)
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py", line 2021, in read_stata
    reader = StataReader(
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\stata.py", line 1172, in __init__
    self.path_or_buf = BytesIO(handles.handle.read())
MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you need the entire dataset at the same time? Can you load it in batches, work with a little at a time, rinse and repeat. Loop through until the processing is finished?

Comment: @nstvnsn That doesn't help (see my answer) since the Pandas Stata reader apparently always reads the entire file into memory :(

Comment: @AKX I am sure they have a good reason for it...but that sounds inconvenient :(

Comment: You may be able to get away with setting up a large swap file/partition on disk, depending on the access patterns.

Comment: @nstvnsn I honestly think it's just an oversight here.

Comment: @Gaju_masare This should be fixed in Pandas 2.0 thanks to my PR.

Answer (score 7):

[By the looks of it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cfeed03306ec1e939c9dcde2cf953af666bb465b/pandas/io/stata.py#L1167-L1175), Pandas's Stata parser presently always reads the entire file into memory (and transforms it into a memory stream).

This is apparently a bit of a regression – if I'm reading [this diff](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/2f0ada3d430f0cc49fa9ab1e7e2e2a7ec23c9616) correctly, the parser has been previously able to just use a file stream from disk.

**EDIT:** Coincidentally, someone has raised a bug report about this recently: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48700

**EDIT 2:** I figured I could just as well try fix this. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/48922

**EDIT 3:** A quarter of a year later, my PR was merged into Pandas 2.0.

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple of libraries made to work seamlessly with pandas (i.e. allow You to use the traditional pandas api) but are optimized for big files

Here's a [link](https://www.datarevenue.com/en-blog/pandas-vs-dask-vs-vaex-vs-modin-vs-rapids-vs-ray)

Additionally, if You don't want to read the article just try

```py
# pip install "modin[dask]"
import modin.pandas as pd
```

Comment: This doesn't help, since [modin uses pandas's `read_stata`](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/blob/2d21561508d351c79dab9e0f62136065ceed2e4a/modin/core/io/io.py#L430-L436).

Comment: then maybe vaex is a better choice in this case

Comment: `vaex` doesn't seem to support Stata files at all.